# Rails + Alchemy CMS - How to set custom layout for user view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alchemy-cms

It is easy to set custom layout in admin page by setting `admin_page_preview_layout:layout_name`  in `config/alchemy/config.yml` file.

But, How do I set custom layout for `Alchemy::PagesController#show` action,

By default `Alchemy::PagesController` uses `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` .
I don’t want to use the `app/views/layout/application.html.erb`,

instead of `application.html.erb`  I want to use custom layout, as I am integrating Alchemy CMS into existing rails project.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Move your existing custom layout to a partial.  Render the partial in application.html.reb.

Comment: Thanks @dbugger I too had a thought about it. But, I have a large application and custom layout would still be used by many other controllers. As of now I am not trying to use Alchemy in complete project.